# Powershell Lines of code count

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-3.0, string-matching

Im having some trouble counting the lines of code in all my powershell projects.
I want to ignore comment sections in my count, unfortunately I am not that good with regular expressions.
So what I want to achieve is to exclude all the "Synopsis help code in functions"

```
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
#>
```

And my own comment blocks

```
<#
Get-ADUser -Identity ThisUserDoesNotExist
ThisCodeIsCommentedOut
#>
```

What I have so far is

```
Get-Content Script.ps1 | ?{$_ -ne "" -and $_ -notlike "#*"}
```

Comment: Think I found a way round it:
function Count-CommentBlock {
    param (
        $ScriptText
    )
    $boolInsideComment = $false
    $lineCounter = 0
    $lineTotal = 0
    $ScriptText = $ScriptText.Trim()
    foreach ($Line in $ScriptText) {
        if ($Line -like "<#*") {
            $boolInsideComment = $true
        }
        elseif ($Line -like "#>*") {
            $boolInsideComment = $false
            $lineCounter++
            $lineTotal += $lineCounter
        }
        if ($boolInsideComment) {
            $lineCounter++
        }
    }
    return $lineTotal
}
This should work?

Comment: why not using my solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you are in v3.0 I suggest to use this script: http://poshcode.org/4789

Here the relevant part modified just to count lines of code of a script file:

```
$file = ".\My_Script_File.ps1"

$fileContentsArray  = Get-Content -Path $file

if ($fileContentsArray)
    {
        $codeLines          = $null
        $tokenAst           = $null
        $parseErrorsAst     = $null
        # Use the PowerShell 3 file parser to create the scriptblock AST, tokens and error collections
        $scriptBlockAst     = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseFile($file, [ref]$tokenAst, [ref]$parseErrorsAst)
        # Calculate the 'lines of code': any line not containing comment or commentblock and not an empty or whitespace line.
        # Remove comment tokens from the tokenAst, remove all double newlines and count all the newlines (minus 1)
        $prevTokenIsNewline = $false
        $codeLines      = @($tokenAst | select -ExpandProperty Kind |  where { $_ -ne "comment" } | where {
                                if ($_ -ne "NewLine" -or (!$prevTokenIsNewline))
                                {
                                    $_
                                }
                            $prevTokenIsNewline = ($_ -eq "NewLine")
                            } | where { $_ -eq "NewLine" }).Length-1
    $codeLines
}
```